# Нужна формула для псевдокласса :nth-child сss

Tags: css

Нужно разместить прямоугольные дивы вот так, я так понимаю лучше всего через :nth-child или через :nth-of-type, помогите пожалуйста с формулой которую надо поместить в псевдокласс. Цифры наверху не нужны, нужно только смещение цветов
[image: прямоугольники выводятся по 4 в ряд со сдвигом]

Comment: Вопрос не понятен, какую формулу хотите ? как написать :nth-of-type()?

Comment: Почему бы просто классы не подписывать очередному порядковому блоку?

Comment: формулу вида (4n+1), классы не надо, будет через шаблонизатор работать, на входе список текста для надписи внутри прямоугольников + картинки, все это выводится через цикл шаблонизатора. Поэтому такая печалька, понятно, что можно через javascript сделать и стили, но думаю это можно решить и таким способом. Просто не могу подобрать формулу для каждого цвета. Цифер этих не будет, это я для проверки формулы их пронумеровал

Comment: Решил проблему по другому. после каждого 4 дива вставляется 5 нулевой ширины, к которому также применяется :nth-child, но так как он не отображается, то следующий элемент уже 6 по счету сдвигается на позицию 5 и так далее. Получается нужный результат.  Пришлось правда в шаблонизатор вводить порядковый номер и уже в HTML проверять на остаток от 4.

Answer (score 3):

На чистом `css` для 4х4

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 200px;
}
   

.parent > div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px
}


.parent > div:nth-child(-3n+13) {
  background: white;
}

.parent > div:nth-child(-3n+1),
.parent > div:nth-child(-3n+14) {
  background: grey;
}

.parent > div:nth-child(-3n+5),
.parent > div:nth-child(-3n+15) {
  background: pink;
}

.parent > div:nth-child(-3n+9),
.parent > div:nth-child(-16n+16) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
</div>
```

Comment: эээ... я наверно сам виноват, не сообщил подробно, вообще число прямоугольников изначально неизвестно, примерно от 6 до 30. То есть их будут постоянно добавлять и убирать и каждый раз это будет разное количество. Если бы их было ровно 16, то я бы не заморачивался бы так, просто через класс раскрасил.

Comment: Nykolay Ryzhov,  обязательно чтобы блоки шли от 1 до 30, или можно от 30 до 1?

Comment: Без разницы, есть файл со списком пронумерованным , его можно сформировать и с обратным отсчетом, на node hbs берет из него этот список и выдает divы на страницу раскрашенные согласно стилям CSS. На самом деле задача из теории множеств, к сожалению из вышки такие вещи уже не помню, а лопатить теорию множеств ради простенькой задачи не хочется. Думал, кто-то тут обладает такими познаниями )))